# rspec-mocks' doubles are designed to only last for one example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-mocks

I've got a question about how to share rspec-mocks' double between examples. I'm writing a new rails app with rspec-mocks `3.1.3`. I'm used to using the old (< 2.14 and and trying to update my knowledge if current rspec usage.

I have a model method:

```
def self.from_strava(activity_id, race_id, user)
  @client ||= Strava::Api::V3::Client.new(access_token: 'abc123')

  activity = @client.retrieve_an_activity(activity_id)

  result_details = {race_id: race_id, user: user}
  result_details[:duration] = activity['moving_time']
  result_details[:date] = Date.parse(activity['start_date'])
  result_details[:comment] = activity['description']
  result_details[:strava_url] = "http://www.strava.com/activities/#{activity_id}"


  Result.create!(result_details)
end
```

And here is the spec:

```
describe ".from_strava" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }
  let(:client) { double(:client) }
  let(:json_response) { JSON.parse(File.read('spec/support/strava_response.json')) }

  before(:each) do
    allow(Strava::Api::V3::Client).to receive(:new) { client }
    allow(client).to receive(:retrieve_an_activity) { json_response }
    allow(Result).to receive(:create!)
  end

  it "sets the duration" do
    expect(Result).to receive(:create!).with(hash_including(duration: 3635))
    Result.from_strava('123', 456, user)
  end

  it "sets the date" do
    expect(Result).to receive(:create!).with(hash_including(date: Date.parse("2014-11-14")))
    Result.from_strava('123', 456, user)
  end
end
```

When I run a single test on it's own it's fine, but when I run the whole `describe ".from_strava"` block it fails with the message

```
Double :client was originally created in one example but has leaked into another example and can no longer be used. rspec-mocks' doubles are designed to only last for one example, and you need to create a new one in each example you wish to use it for.
```

I understand what it's saying, but surely this is an appropriate use of a `double` being used in 2 examples. After all, the `client` double isn't important to the example, it's just a way for me to load the canned response. I guess I could use WebMock but that seems very low-level and doesn't translate well to the actual code written. We should only be asserting one thing per example after all.

I had thought about replacing the `client` double with a call to

```
allow(Strava::Api::V3::Client).to receive_message_chain(:new, :retrieve_an_activity) { json_response }
```

but that doesn't seem to be the right approach either, given that the documentation states that  `receive_message_chain` should be a code smell.

So if I shouldn't use `receive_message_chain`, shared `client` double and also follow the standard DRY principle then how should I fix this?

I would love some feedback on this.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: It because you are caching the `@client` in a class instance variable. If you change the `@client ||=...` to `@clinet = ...` it will be fine

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think about that as an option, I assumed it was something new in rspec-mock. It's obvious now you point it out. Clearly coding at midnight is not the best!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> surely this is an appropriate use of a double being used in 2 examples.

No, it's not. :) You're trying to use a class variable; do not do that because the variable doesn't span examples. The solution is to set the client each time i.e. in each example.

Bad:

```
@client ||= Strava::Api::V3::Client.new(access_token: 'abc123')
```

Good:

```
@client = Strava::Api::V3::Client.new(access_token: 'abc123')
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think about that as an option, I assumed it was something new in rspec-mock. It's obvious now you point it out. Clearly coding at midnight is not the best!

Answer (score 21):

Caching clients for external components can often be really desired (keeping alive connections/any SSL setup that you might need, etc.) and removing that for the sake of fixing an issue with tests is not a desirable solution.

In order to fix your test (without refactoring your code), you can do the following to clear the instance variable after each of your tests:

```
after { Result.instance_variable_set("@client", nil) }
```

While admittedly, this is not the cleanest solution, it seems to be the simplest and achieves both, lets you have a clear setup with no state shared in between tests, and keep your client cached in "normal" operation mode.

Comment: this feels better considering we don't have to give up memoization

Answer (score 3):

I had the same use case in an app of mine, and we solved it by extracting the cacheing into a private method and then stubbing that method to return the double (instead of stubbing the `new` method directly).

For example, in the class under test:

```
def self.from_strava(activity_id, race_id, user)
  activity = strava_client.retrieve_an_activity(activity_id)
  ...
end

private
def self.strava_client
  @client ||= Strava::Api::V3::Client.new(access_token: 'abc123')
end
```

And in the spec:

```
let(:client) { double(:client) }

before { allow(described_class).to receive(:strava_client).and_return(client) }

...
```

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Add `after { order.vendor_service = nil }` to balance the `before` block.  Or read on...

I ran into this, and it was not obvious where it was coming from.  In order_spec.rb model tests, I had this:

```
  describe 'order history' do
    before do
      service = double('VendorAPI')
      allow(service).to receive(:order_count).and_return(5)
      order.vendor_service = service
    end   

    # tests here  ..
  end
```

And in my `Order` model:

```
  def too_many_orders?
    @@vendor_service ||= VendorAPI.new(key: 'abc', account: '123')
    return @@vendor_service.order_count > 10
  end
```

This worked fine when I only ran rspec on order_spec.rb

I was mocking something completely different in order_controller_spec.rb a little differently, using `allow_any_instance_of()` instead of `double` and `allow`:

```
  allow_any_instance_of(Order).to receive(:too_many_orders?).and_return(true)
```

This, too, tested out fine.

The confounding trouble is that when I ran the full suite of tests, I got the OP's error on the controller mock -- the one using `allow_any_instance`.  This was very hard to track down, as the problem (or at least my solution) lay in the model tests where I use `double/allow`.

To fix this, I added an `after` block clearing the class variable @@vendor_service, balancing the `before` block's action:

```
  describe 'order history' do
    before do
      service = double('VendorAPI')
      allow(service).to receive(:order_count).and_return(5)
      order.vendor_service = service
    end   

    after do
      order.vendor_service = nil 
    end

    # tests here  ..
  end
```

This forced the `||= VendorAPI.new()` to use the real `new` function in later unrelated tests, not the mock object.